# Some data missing from my facebook app query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was attempting to gather some data from friends on Facebook. However some of the fields were left blank for some users. I then looked to see if the data was present on the pages manually to which for some it was. I even asked for the correct permissions.

I guess what I am trying to ask is if there is if data can still be hidden from the app even if I ask for the right permissions and it is manually viewable directly on their page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, users can control what data is available to the applications which their friends use. The settings for this can be found [here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view)

The settings look like this:

[image: screenshot of settings]

Users can untick the boxes for the information which they do not want to appear in friends' applications. This information will still be visible to their friends - but apps that their friends install cannot access the data.